# Pass the collection result of a method as params argument

Tags: c#, collections, parameters

I have a method that takes params and I want to provide those params with another method. Example:

```
public void Process(params string[] words)
{
    // do some stuff
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetWords()
{
    yield return "test";
}

Process(GetWords()); // Error collection of strings must be passed individually
```

However this is not allowed because the result is considered a single parameter of type IEnumerable instead of a set of parameters type string. I've tried using ToArray and ToList, same problem. Is there a way to use the result of a method as params argument?

Edit: The problem occurs when you pass another argument first. The problem is I need to keep access to the first parameter but not the others. That can be done by letting the method create all parameters, calling it separately and keeping a reference to the first element.

Comment: Do you mean it should be the same as calling `Process("first", "test")`, like Process(Enumerable.Repeat("first", 1).Concat(GetWords()).ToArray()) would do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
    Process(GetWords().ToArray());
```

Comment: what is the output you are expecting ?

Comment: Oh it's because I also want to add another parameter first, didn't think that would matter. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Anyway your answer is correct to what the question first was.